# Error *170 FastCGI sent in stderr on Phalcon 4.*

Tags: php, phalcon

2022/05/17 09:02:46 [error] 22404#22404: *170 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  The 'compiledPath' option is deprecated. Use 'path' instead. in /vagrant/phalcon/public/index.php on line 24PHP message: PHP Deprecated:  The 'compiledSeparator' option is deprecated. Use 'separator' instead. in /vagrant/phalcon/public/index.php on line 24" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.63.1, server: dev.vagrant.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "192.168.63.252"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

from phalcon version 4
volt config path not compiledPath

The 'compiledPath' option is deprecated. Use 'path' instead.